# ffmpegコマンドで成功していたフォント指定がffmpeg-goではエラーになる

Tags: go, ffmpeg, yaml

[ffmpeg-go](https://github.com/u2takey/ffmpeg-go)を使って以下のコマンドを実行しているのですが、なぜかGolangから実行したときにフォントが見つからないエラーになります。
コンパイルされたコマンドをコピーしてそれを直打ちするとフォントのエラーが発生しません。
なぜでしょうか。

**ffmpeg-goの出力**

```
2023/12/27 22:48:21 compiled command: ffmpeg -i tmp/211045067/input.mp4 -acodec aac -ar 44100 -r 60 -s 1920x1080 -vcodec libx264 -vf drawtext=text='sample':fontfile='C\\:/Windows/Fonts/msgothic.ttc':fontsize=42:fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=20:y=h-th-30,ass=tmp/211045067/subtitle.ass tmp/440085866/output.mp4 -y
```

**エラー（ffmpegのエラー）**

```
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
```

こちらがGoのプログラムから実行すると出ますが、コマンド直打ちだと出ません。

**コマンド実行部分のコードを記載**

```
const TextBox = "drawtext=text='%s by %s':fontfile='%s':fontsize=42:fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=20:y=h-th-30"

        if err := ffmpeg_go.
            Input(input).
            Output(output,
                ffmpeg_go.KwArgs{
                    "r":      strconv.Itoa(fps),
                    "vcodec": "libx264",
                    "acodec": "aac",
                    "ar":     "44100",
                    "s":      "1920x1080",
                    "vf":     fmt.Sprintf(TextBox, title, author, font) + ",ass=" + ass,
                },
            ).OverWriteOutput().ErrorToStdOut().Run(); err == nil {
            return nil
        }
```

フォント名はyamlファイルで渡しています。

```yaml
fontPath: C\\:/Windows/Fonts/msgothic.ttc
```

Comment: yaml の中の `C\\:` を `C\:` にすると、どうでしょうか。

Comment: その方法で行けました！ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

エスケープの仕様が何レベルか関係する問題です。

#### FFmpegが解釈するエスケープ

- `ffmpeg` コマンドの引数におけるフィルター指定は「`:`」（コロン）で区切られます
- 値に「`:`」自体が含まれる場合は「`\`」（バックスラッシュ）による[エスケープが必要です](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Notes-on-filtergraph-escaping)

これにより、`C:/Windows` という値は、`C\:/Windows` とする必要が有ります。

#### シェルなどでのエスケープ

- 「`\`」は `ffmpeg` コマンド以外でもエスケープ用の記号として使われることが多いです
- この場合、「`\`」の表現は「`\`」自体をエスケープして「`\\`」となります

よって、FFmpegに渡したい値が `C\:/Windows` の場合、 `C\\:/Windows` となります。質問のケースではこれがYAMLファイルに記述されていました。

#### YAMLでのエスケープ

- YAMLでも「`\`」はエスケープに使われます
- 但し、「`"`」（ダブルクォーテーション）に[囲まれた部分でのみ解釈されます](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#57-escaped-characters)

よって、`C\\:/Windows` が表現するのは、そのまま `C\\:/Windows` です。これを `ffmpeg` コマンドに渡すと、「`\`」が一つ余分となり、質問のエラーが発生します。

つまり、YAMLで `C\:/Windows` という文字列を表現したい場合、`C\:/Windows` か `"C\\:/Windows"` が正しいです。